# console.log() does not appear in my terminal (nwjs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit, nw.js

In my nwjs app, I load a *_launch.js* file from an HTML file:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_launch.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And in my *_launch.js* file, I fire up the the Node processes I need for an express server and socketIO.

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').Server(app),
    io = require('socket.io')(server),
    gui = require('nw.gui'),

    __curDir = process.cwd(),

    //keep the logic for the IO connections separate
    ioServer = require(__curDir + '/server.js');

//configure Express to default web requests to /workspace/ folder
app.use(express.static(__curDir + '/workspace'));

ioServer.init(io, console);

server.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('HTTP server listening on *:3000');
    window.location = 'http://localhost:3000/MyApp/';
});
```

The app launches just fine, and my express/socketIO connections are all perfectly working.

But while the *console.log()* in the server.listen() callback appears in my terminal, any messages I try to log from the *server.js* file (required earlier) never show up anywhere.

Any ideas why?

Per the nwjs wiki, any files loaded via *require()* should be running in the Node context (and mine otherwise appears to be) -- but for whatever reason, I cannot use *console.log()* to view logged information.

Comment: The first code block shows '_launch.css', not a js file inclusion. Is this just the wrong code you pasted ?

Comment: WHOOPS yes, I cut the wrong part of the HTML file. Updated now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please look at the list of [changes related to node](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Changes-related-to-node) in the nw.js wiki.

> Since node-webkit supports GUI applications instead of console applications, the output of console.log() (and other similar methods such as console.warn() and console.error()) is redirected to WebKit's console. You may see it in your “Developer Tools” window (on its “Console” tab).

Comment: Problem is that I dont see it in the console.

Comment: I can see the outputs of console.log in the console window on Linux (openSUSE) and in the 'Developer Tools Window's Console Tab' on Windows (Windows 10).

Comment: Sorry for marking this as the answer a year later... but that did seem to be it for me.

Answer (score 24):

You have to run DevTools for Background Page by right clicking on your app and choosing the <kbd>Inspect background page</kbd> option from the context menu.

[[image: Inspect background page]

<sup>click for full size image</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfPtY.png)

Here is a related bug report: [0.13-beta3 console.log doesn't work in node context](http://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/4254)

Comment: This works for me, it should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 17):

Just pass `--enable-logging=stderr` in `chromium-args` in your **package.json**:

```
{
    ...
    "chromium-args": "--enable-logging=stderr",
    ...
}
```

Or use the `Inspect background page` DevTools as [@Jakub Bejnarowicz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35127692/537648) has pointed out.