# Don't see logs on the server side when using console.log

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-webkit

This is the first time in my life I touch js or node so please bear with me.

I am trying to make my app output logs on the server side.

```
  getUser.onclick = function () {
    console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (req.readyState === 4 && req.status === 200) {
        var user = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
        results.innerText += user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName + '\n';
      }
    };
    req.open("GET", "/user");
    req.send();
```

Now according to this: [Node js console.log is not showing anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33196520/node-js-console-log-is-not-showing-anything) 
this should work. However, this sheds more light on where the logs are actually going: [console.log() does not appear in my terminal (nwjs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29496847/console-log-does-not-appear-in-my-terminal-nwjs)

When I compare the browser and console this is what I see: 
[image]

Each Get User button click corresponds to a single request. On the right side in there is a log message that I intended to be on the server side. Namely `Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/`

But I don't see it anywhere on the terminal from where I've started the app. As I understand this is an idiosyncrasy of webkit involved applications. How would I override this behavior.

The suggestion to `--enable-logging=stderr in chromium-args in my package.json` did not do it for me.

***UPDATE***

I am using code base here as a starting point. Just inserted log statement in the get request https://github.com/thlorenz/hyperwatch/tree/master/examples/express-app

I assumed that app.js is the back end code since it is what processes the requests. Am I wrong?

Comment: `console.log` on clientside prints into the browser's console. `console.log` on serverside prints on the server console (or log file), depending on how you're running your server code. You can't print to server console using clientside `console.log`. What is your serverside code?

Comment: @Amadan You were right. After I've inserted logs into the app.js they've started to work. Please convert into an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 0):

In **NW.js** you can:

- `right-click > Inspect` to see the Chromium Dev Tools for the window
- `right-click > Inspect background page` to see the Chromium Dev Tools for the Node instance

Alternatively, there is *nwdc*, a tool which lets you see console messages in the command prompt/shell/terminal:

- https://github.com/nwutils/nwdc